# Copy text in chrome DevTools/Console panel not work normally

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, macos-monterey

**Describe the bug**

Recently, while using Chrome (version 112.0.5615.49) on macOS (version 12.6.3), I have encountered an issue when copying and pasting from the Console panel in DevTools. After selecting a word and copying it, when I paste it, it always shifts 2 characters backwards. What could be the reason for this?

**To Reproduce**

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Any page, F12 to open `devtools`, switch to `console` panel
2. Select and focus on a word(for example: the word 'Uncaught' in sentence `Uncaught ReferenceError:`), do `cmd + c` or `right click & select copy` on this word.
3. `cmd + v` or `right click & select paste` anywhere, you get error word, `caught R`

**Expected behavior**

Copy 'Uncaught', paste will print 'Uncaught'

**Screenshots**

[image: screen recording gif]

[same screen recording video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoCjLGokGKA)

**Desktop**

- OS: macOS (12.6.3 (21G419))
- Browser [Chrome]
- Version [112.0.5615.49]

So, is it a chrome bug? or waiting for offical upgrade to fix it?

Comment: I've reset chrome, but not working.

Comment: I uninstall it, and install the lastest version of chrome again, still not working.

Comment: At last, I downgrade a version of 104, it goes well, but I look for the pkg for a long time. And I found not settings for disabling upgrade chrome. What a horriable thing. A day wasted : (

Comment: 112.0.5615.137 same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76059998/the-string-copied-from-the-chrome-console-is-different-from-what-i-selected

Comment: here are some other version info reported by people in non-answers posted as answers: Chrome Version 112.0.5615.165 using Ubuntu, Edge version 113.0.1774.50, ubuntu with the chrome 112.0.5615.121, Windows 10 Chrome 112.0.5615.138

Comment: not sure if related: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=459319 from googling "`site:bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues console copy 112 OR 113 OR 114 OR 115`"

Comment: also apparently happening on macOS sonoma Version 119.0.6045.123 (Official Build) (arm64)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

20230504: Today I upgrade to `113.0.5672.63`(macOS), all goes well now. Below are my personal little notes.

---

Finnaly it fixed with new version 112.0.5615.121. What a horriable days.

Now it surely chrome bug, not my mac's problem.

Everyone should upgrade chrome to avoid it.

===20230417===

It broken again. I send a feedback report to chrome, but no reply yet.

===20230419===

I check new upgrade everyday. Now is `112.0.5615.137`, still bad ;(

===20230504===

More and more people could reproduce(macOS/Windows/Ubuntu), I think all of v112.x chrome in this post mentioned work bad.

Saddly, I still not received any email about that I seed the feedback 20 days defore, and I don't know how to trace the progress. Any bro knows how to submit the feedback to chrome to be fix more efficient.

I seem to have gotten used to this headache-inducing bug and will quietly wait for the official fix(laughing cry :)

---

After I ready post my hopeless words. I suddenly realized that I hadn't actively checked for updates in a long time, and just now I found that there was an update available when I opened 'About Google Chrome'. I updated to version **113.0.5672.63 (macOS)**, and after restarting Chrome, it seems that the issue has finally been fixed. That's great news!

Please check your chrome update, I think v113.x fixed it, but I'm not sure if the update has been released for other operating systems yet, check yourself guys.

Comment: Can you link your chrome's report ?

Comment: @Seba99 I make a big effort to find out where is my feedback, finally find, but no url, only a record, details in picture link. https://imgur.com/gallery/055O7jM

Comment: Oh ! Really sorry ^^' I thought it was some king of public bug report I could have followed ..

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue when trying to copy text from an error log (red).

So if a text is "bla bli blu" and you want to select "bli", then select "a b" instead.

That's a -2 character translation of the selection beginning and end.

If you forget to do that then when you paste what you copied you just have to "guess" what are the two missing leading characters and also erase the last two.

Please Chromium team fix this since it's already frustrating to be dealing with an error to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome Canary, `115.0.5749.0` this issue seems to have been fixed.

OS MacOS 12.5

EDIT: I got beaten by 8 minutes