# The string copied from the Chrome console is different from what I selected

Tags: google-chrome

For example, in the picture below, I selected "globalState" and copied it by pressing "command+c". But, when I pasted it by pressing "command+v", it displayed as "obalState t". It seems that the selected part has been shifted two spaces to the right.

[image]